# Converting nested JSON to flat JSON with TypeScript /JS/RxJS / map/reduce/filter whatever,

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash, data-conversion

How can I convert (without complicated foreach loops), if possible with existing JS-Libraries (RxJS for Observables, Lodash/Underscore/whatever)

following structure:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "content": {
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "prop": [
                            {
                                "key": "BAR",
                                "value": "Bar getting better"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "FOO",
                                "value": "Foo is cool"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

into this one easly?

```
{
    "BAR": "Bar getting better",
    "FOO": "Foo is cool"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lodash, use [`_.keyBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy) and then [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues)

```js
var data = {"result":[{"content":{"resources":[{"prop":[{"key":"BAR","value":"Bar getting better"},{"key":"FOO","value":"Foo is cool"}]}]}}]},
    input = data.result[0].content.resources[0].prop;

var result = _.mapValues(_.keyBy(input, 'key'), 'value');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much,.. Maybe one more question: How can I convert it back in to the big structure?

Comment: `_.map(obj, function(v, k) { return { key: k, value: v }})`

Comment: Or `_.map(obj, (v, k) => ({key: k, value: v}))`

Comment: This does not take into account that both `result.length` and `resources.length` may be `> 1`.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific data structure you can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and return object.

```js
var data = {"result":[{"content":{"resources":[{"prop":[{"key":"BAR","value":"Bar getting better"},{"key":"FOO","value":"Foo is cool"}]}]}}]}

var result = data.result[0].content.resources[0].prop.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e.key] = e.value;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**ES6** version with arrow function

```js
var data = {"result":[{"content":{"resources":[{"prop":[{"key":"BAR","value":"Bar getting better"},{"key":"FOO","value":"Foo is cool"}]}]}}]}
var ar = data.result[0].content.resources[0].prop;

var result = ar.reduce((r, e) => (r[e.key] = e.value, r), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's an array of objects.

Comment: Your arrow function doesn't need `return`. Just use `(r, e) => (r[e.key] = e.value, r)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with vanilla **Javascript ES6** but it is a little complicated (I didn't test it):

```
var data = ...
var resultData = {}

data.result.forEach(result => result.content.resources.forEach(resource => resource.prop.forEach(prop => resultData[prop.key] = prop.value)))
```

Or if you have only one item for the toplevel arrays, then try this which is **Javascript ES5**:

```
var data = ...
var resultData = {}

data.result[0].content.resources[0].prop.forEach(function(prop) {
    resultData[prop.key] = prop.value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the other solutions here is either

1. They select the array at `data.result[0].content.resources[0].prop`, which does not take into account that both `result` and `resources` arrays may be of length **larger that one**.
2. Nested `forEach` is hard to read and reason about.

To help with this, I've made a small library, [deep-reduce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-reduce), that helps you reduce / untangle values inside deep nested objects. [deep-reduce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-reduce) is similar to [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control), though it traverses deeply in nested objects / arrays.

On your data, you may use it like this

```
// if path is ending in prop.number, 
// then `item` is the object we want to untangle
let untanglePropItems = (reduced, item, path) => {
  if (path.match(/prop\.\d+$/)) {
    reduced[item.key] = item.value
  }
  return reduced
}

// the reduced value is returned
let reduced = deepReduce(deepNestedObject, untanglePropItems)
```

[Here is a demo in RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/8yx0mz6cv4zi).